# Divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{n}}\cos\left(n^2 \pi \gamma\right)$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, mobius-function, euler-mascheroni-constant

We denote the Möbius function as  $\mu(n)$, see its definition from this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html).

On the other hand it is not known if the Euler-Mascheroni constant is irrational.

After I've read a [MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201250/is-sum-k-1n-sink2-bounded-by-a-constant-m) I would like to ask a related question.

> **Question.** Is feasible to deduce if $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{n}}\cos\left(n^2 \pi \gamma\right),\tag{1}$$
>    is divergent? I am asking about what work can be done. **Many thanks.**

If you want to add a some words or a draft about if our series can be summable by any Cesàro means it also is good.

Comment: I don't see any hope with current technology. We don't know whether $\gamma$ is irrational. With $n^2$ replaced by $n$, it is still difficult.

Comment: I recommend you reading this MO post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164874/is-it-possible-to-show-that-sum-n-1-infty-frac-mun-sqrtn-diverg?noredirect=1&lq=1 which gives divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt n}$.

Comment: I saw the answer from the MathOverflow's post I my 
thoughts after I did a graph of the partial sums  $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{n}}\cos\left(n^2 \pi \gamma\right)$ for some $N's$, is that maybe someone can do some work about it. I accept your words and many thanks for your great reference @i707107